# Finding and replacing contents of a node

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xpath

I have 2 XML documents that look something like:

1. doc1

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <import>
     <collection>
       <name>II_14714_1889</name>
       <metadata>512143197.xml</metadata>
     </collection>
     <collection>
       <name>II_14714_1884</name>
       <metadata>512142173.xml</metadata>
     </collection>
     <collection>
       <name>II_14714_1886</name>
       <metadata>512142685.xml</metadata>
     </collection>
   </import>
   ```
2. doc2

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <collection>
     <record>
       <datafield tag="000">
         <subfield code="x">512143197</subfield>
         <subfield code="r">...</subfield>
       </datafield>
       <datafield tag="200">
         <subfield code="e">1989</subfield>
       </datafield>
     </record>
     <record>
       <datafield tag="000">
         <subfield code="x">512143180</subfield>
         <subfield code="r">...</subfield>
       </datafield>
       <datafield tag="200">
         <subfield code="e">1970</subfield>
       </datafield>
     </record>
     <record>
       <datafield tag="000">
         <subfield code="x">512143198</subfield>
         <subfield code="r">...</subfield>
       </datafield>
       <datafield tag="200">
         <subfield code="e">1990</subfield>
       </datafield>
     </record>
   </collection>
   ```

What I am trying to do is to get text from metadata node in doc1, search for it in doc2 within subfield code="x" nodes and if it is there get subfield code="e" text of the same record node and replace corresponding doc1 //collection/name node text with it.

For now I'm using the following code

```
foreach (XmlNode xmlMetadata in doc1.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//collection/metadata"))
        {
                string id = xmlMetadata.InnerText.ToString();
                string resultString = Regex.Match(id, @"\d\d\d\d+").Value;
                MessageBox.Show(resultString);
                foreach (XmlNode xmlSubfield in doc2.SelectNodes("//record/datafield[@tag='000']/subfield[@code='x']"))
                {
                    string subfield = xmlSubfield.InnerText.ToString();
                    if (subfield == resultString)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(xmlSubfield.SelectSingleNode("../datafield[@tag='200']/subfield[@code='e']").InnerText.ToString());
                        string year = xmlSubfield.SelectSingleNode("../datafield[@tag='200']/subfield[@code='e']").InnerText.ToString();
                        year = Regex.Match(godina, @"\d\d\d\d").Value;
                        doc2.SelectSingleNode("../datafield[@tag='200']/subfield[@code='e']").InnerText = godina;
                    }

                }


        }
```

But it shows "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error at second MessageBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting all `subfield` nodes in your first XPath expression

```
//record/datafield[@tag='000']/subfield[@code='x']
```

So you have to add another `../` at the beginning to the XPath expression with the `MessageBox.Show` to reach the record-node level.

```
MessageBox.Show(xmlSubfield.SelectSingleNode("../../datafield[@tag='200']/subfield[@code='e']").InnerText.ToString());
                                              ^^^ here
```

EDIT: A simpler way to achieve this is

```
foreach (XmlNode xmlSubfield in doc2.SelectNodes("//record[datafield[@tag='000']/subfield[@code='x'] = '"+resultString+"']/datafield[@tag='200']/subfield[@code='e']"))
{ 
  MessageBox.Show(xmlSubfield.InnerText.ToString());
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks I figured thats why SelectSingleNode returned Null. Any suggestions how to do this simplier?